# Bean validation multiple property nodes

Tags: spring, annotations, javabeans, bean-validation, null-pointer

I'm using bean validation 1.1, and I would like to validate a bean (at class level) and add feedback to the user for multiple fields.

High level what I want to achieve (omitted code for readability)

```
@RequestCheck
public class Request {
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private String param3;
}

public class RequestCheckValidator implements ConstraintValidator<RequestCheck, Request> {
    //...
    public boolean isValid(final Request request, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (request.param1 != null || request.param2 != null || request.param3 != null)
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            final ConstraintViolationBuilder violationBuilder = context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("There are missing parameters.");
            if (request.param1 == null) {
                valid = false;
                violationBuilder.addPropertyNode("param1");
            }
            if (request.param2() == null) {
                valid = false;
                violationBuilder.addPropertyNode("param2");
            }
            if (request.param3() == null) {
                valid = false;
                violationBuilder.addPropertyNode("param3");
            }
            violationBuilder.addConstraintViolation();
            //return ...
        }
    }
```

The problem is that adding a second `addProperyNode("...")` throws a nullpointer.
How do you correctly add an extra parameter to the feedback when the validation applies to the class?

-- EDIT --
To clearify: I need this annotation at class level, because the validation depends on a combination of the fields. They need all to be present or none of them must be present.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using just simple annotation for bean's fields validations in spring?

Comment: Because they depend on each other. There are some fields that all need to be present or none must be present

Comment: Spring's JSR3 validation supports cross filed validation. No need to reinvent wheel.

Comment: If you have a code example of an out of the box working annotation for that, I would love to see it. But for as far as I know, with Spring's validation you need to implement your own validation at class level as well... Which is basically the same. They use Exceptions as feedback though, while Bean validation uses ViolationConstraints (which is cleaner feedback imo). Anyway, I prefer to use the standard Java approach.

Answer (score 2):

Ok this was actually pretty easy, you just need to create a builder per violation:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("if a parameter is supplied, please provide all parametes. param1 is Missing")
               .addPropertyNode("param1")
               .addConstraintViolation();
```